# Return BLOB column Which is Empty Or Not Empty as 1 or 0

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with BLOB column that some row has BLOB, some empty.

```
1 Apple   BLOB-8KiB
2 Banana  
3 Pear    BLOB-6KiB
4 Orange  BLOB-7KiB
```

Is there any way I can use PHP MYSQL to get the array like this:

```
$fruit = array(
array("1",Apple,1),
array("2",Banana,0),
array("3",Pear,1),
array("4",Orange,1)
);
```

I just want to change the BLOB data with 1, Empty with 0 in my PHP array. Pls help.

Answer (score 1):

Your select statement can use IF and ISNULL (note these are not widely implemented in the same format on different database backends, this is for MySQL).

So you would use:

```
SELECT ID, Name, IF(ISNULL(BlobField), 0, 1) FROM TableName
```

IF allows you to choose one of two values according to a logical operation.

ISNULL returns true or false according to whether or not the value is NULL